# Win32 data types equivalant in Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to convert a C++ library which is using widely DWORD, CString and BYTE in the program, and now I am converting the code from C++ Win32 library to linux program .
Also I am using openSUSE 12.3 and Anjuta IDE to do this , please help me which types I should use instead of mentioned types ?
I think I should use unsigned int for DWORD and string for CString and unsigned char instead of BYTE is it right ?

Comment: That seems reasonable. DWORD and BYTE are just simple typedefs for those types, however std::string and CString are entirely different so might need bigger code rewrites.

Comment: Replacing CString class (Microsoft's own) would be not easy task. Take a look at this class that seems to do what you want - http://code.google.com/p/gtatools/source/browse/trunk/src/libgtaformats/src/gtaformats/util/CString.h?spec=svn245&r=245.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`CString` will not convert directly to `std::string`, but it is a rough equivalent.

`BYTE` is indeed `unsigned char` and `DWORD` is `unsigned int`. `WORD` is `unsigned short`.

You should definitely use `typedef actual_type WINDOWS_NAME;` to fix the code up, don't go through everywhere to replace the types. I would add a new headerfile that is called something like "wintypes.h", and include that everywhere the "windows.h" is used.

Edit for comment: 
With `CString`, it really depends on how it is used (and whether the code is using what MS calls "Unicode" or "ASCII" strings). I would be tempted to create a class `CString` and then use `std::string` inside that. Most of it can probably be done by simply calling the equivalent `std::string` function, but some functions may need a bit more programming - again, it does depend on what member functions of `CString` are actually being used.

For `LP<type>`, that is just a pointer to the `<type>`, so `typedef BYTE* LPBYTE;` and `typedef DWORD* LPDWORD;` will do that.

Comment: Tanx for your response , but could you tell me what should I do about CString and also LPBYTE ?

Comment: Edit added to the original post for `CString` and `LPBYTE`(etc).

Comment: I would say rather that he _should_ globally search and replace all instances of `BYTE` by `unsigned char`.  Using `BYTE` was a bad idea to begin with (except in code directly using the Windows interface), and it's better to get rid of it.

Comment: Yes, in an ideal world. But assuming this is widely used, it's a lot of work to gloablly change that, and it makes "unnecessary changes to working code", which, assuming the code isn't being completely overhauled in all sorts of other aspects, isn't my philosophy. They are `typedef`'d in the original Windows header file, so it should be fine to `typedef` them to the right thing in the ported code too.

Comment: @user1356386 Just having loads of fun because of `DWORD` being 64 bits.

Comment: What is the Linux equivalent of HANDLE?

Comment: The `HANDLE` type is not directly translatable to Linux, as `HANDLE` is used in several different ways (in Windows, it's a `void *`, but you can't necessarily translate it to that in Linux, since for example a "file-handle" is `int` (file descriptor number))

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use uint32_t and uint8_t from <stdint.h> for DWORD and BYTE and normal char * or const char * for strings (or the std:string class for C++).

Probably best thought is to use typedefs for existing code:

```
typedef unsigned char             BYTE;
```

These can be changed easily.

If you rewrite code use char, int, long were useful and the (u)intX_t types, were you need a defined size.

Answer (score 2):

- `DWORD` = `uint32_t`
- `BYTE` = `uint8_t`

These types are not OS specifics and were added to C++11. You need to `include <cstdint>` to get them. If you have an old compiler you could use boost/cstdint, which is header only.

Use `std::string` instead `CString`, but you will need to change some code.

With these changes your code should compile on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: `CString` and `std::string` serve the same purpose. The former is a class written by Microsoft, the latter is part of the C++ standard library and ships with all compilers, including Visual Studio. But these classes have slightly different APIs, so you will have to modify the existing code to use `std::string` instead of `CString`. Unlike `uint32_t` and `uint8_t` where you could just search/replace the code...

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

CString -> maybe basic_string<TCHAR> ?
```