# Linux Implementation of HANDLE and DCB

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I have to migrate a program to Linux that uses the windows HANDLE and DCB e.g:

```
int DLMSClient::GXGetCommState(HANDLE hWnd, LPDCB DCB) { //code }
```

How would I go about migrating these to Linux?

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297073/win32-data-types-equivalant-in-linux), I have figured out how to migrate DWORD, WORD and BYTE, but how would I go about these new types?

Also, a source where I can gain understanding on this process may be helpful.

Comment: LPDCB will be a pointer to a DCB struct defined somewhere, that you will have to convert over member by member. HANDLE is normally a kernel handle that would translate to a file descriptor (an int) on posix - but here I see it is being misused to carry a HWND - and converting that over to linux is going to be interesting as the target type will be determined entirely by the windowing framework you are converting to. If any.

Comment: What I understand is that you need to communicate with a device on a serial Bus. That might be a lot easier to look for a linux serial communication library instead of porting this.

Comment: @Emilien can you point me towards a page that explains the functioning behind this for Windows? I use Linux and am unfamiliar with the windows serial communication libraries.

Comment: The second link in Simon's answer says that "a DCB structure defines the control setting for a serial communications device."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably working with serial ports, but in Linux a serial port is managed somewhat differently than in Windows. There is not a simple one-to-one mapping between them. Moreover, in Linux, serial port *are* terminals, and they may surprise you.

I'll try and explain a bit:

- A Windows `HANDLE` will map to a Linux file descriptor. That is a plain `int` value.
- In Windows you get the `HANDLE` with `CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM1", ...)`. In Linux you get it with `open("/dev/ttyS0",  O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY)`. The `O_NOCTTY` flag is to avoid making this port your controlling terminal (you do not want a surprising controlling terminal!).
- In Windows you close the `HANDLE` with `CloseHandle(handle)`. In Linux, with `close(fd)`.
- In Windows you configure the serial port with `BuildCommDCB()` and `SetCommState(...)`. In Linux you do it with `tcgetattr()`, `cfmakeraw()`, `cfsetspeed()`, and `tcsetattr()`, among others... You probably want the `raw` mode.
- In Windows you send data with `WriteFile()` and receive with `ReadFile()`. In Linux you use `read()` and `write()`.

I hope this will be enough to get you started.

Comment: This is very good description, but can we get an example gather all of these points.

Answer (score 1):

`HANDLE` is defined as a pointer to void (`PVOID` = `void*`)

(see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

`LPDCB` is defined as "a pointer to a DCB structure"

(see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)